# Updating Key Event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datagrid

Hey I have a problem with a grid I am using in Javascript. I'll try tell you what I've tried first. Basically it has a key event for the button delete attached to it. However I want to override this and do something else for this specific keyup event. There is other keyevents that need to stay but I need to change what happens when the delete button  is pushed when I have a row selected.

I've tried a couple of things including targeting it with bind and unbind but nothing seems to work.

I attached an alert to the delete function to fire showing what element is firing the function and it's coming back with dataGrid.

Also I tried stop propogation but no luck.

```
                   $(".divDataGrid")
                    .keyup(function(event) {
                        console.log("seamus");
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        // Do something
                    });
```

However none of this works. Has anyone out there run into a similar problem or has anyone an idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you are trying to prevent the default action on button. In that case what you need to use is `event.preventDefault();`

`event.stopPropagation();` will just stop the event from bubbling up; will not restrict its default action.